How to query a table whose name is built from a PL/pgSQL function result?
I've below function that takes a datetime and returns an integer.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_partition_index(datetime timestamp with time zone)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
DECLARE
    partitions integer := 52;
    datetime_utc timestamp := datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
    week_of_year integer := DATE_PART('week', datetime_utc);
    partition_index integer := week_of_year % partitions;
BEGIN
    RETURN partition_index;
END;
$function$

There are 52 tables in the database with names metric_event_1, metric_event_2, ..., metric_event_10, ... and metric_event_51.
Now I want query the table based on the result of the get_partition_index function.
select * from `metric_event_+billing_event_partition_index_new(now())` limit 10;

But the above query returns error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: select * from `billing_events_+billing_event_partition_index...



Remove the backtick ` from your code. Besides that, this won't work anyway, you can't create a table name in your FROM like this. The name of the table must be clear before the query can be executed. Change your logic.

By the way, why do you think you need this? Usually you would put the week number in the WHERE condition, and let the query planner select the correct partition.

@FrankHeikens - This is really old code and the table is partitioned into 52 and using triggers to insert duplicate records into partitioned tables based on the function above. Now I have different request to get last 24 hours.

Better function (still don't use!)
A simpler SQL version of your function could work like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_partition_index(datetime timestamptz)
  RETURNS numeric
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT EXTRACT(week FROM $1 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') % 52;
$func$;

That fixes the syntax and improves technicalities. The whole idea is still nonsense on multiple levels.
Nonsense levels
For starters, names metric_event_1 ... metric_event_51, that's 51 tables, not 52 like you state. And there are actually 53 ISO weeks. EXTRACT returns week numbers from 1 to 53 accordingly. Your % 52 would make a mess including a week "0" ...
Your try with backticks raised a syntax error as backticks are not used for quoting in Postgres (or standard SQL) at all. See:

Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL

But the attempt is nonsense on a deeper level. You cannot parameterize / interpolate identifiers (incl. table names) in plain SQL. You could concatenate the query string in your client, or use dynamic SQL:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_rows_from_metric_event(_tstz timestamptz, _limit int = 10)
  RETURNS SETOF metric_event  -- actual table name!
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
BEGIN
-- RAISE NOTICE '%',  -- to debug
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   format('SELECT * FROM metric_event_%s LIMIT %s', EXTRACT(week FROM _tstz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') % 52, _limit);
END
$func$;

Call:
SELECT * FROM public.get_rows_from_metric_event(now());

Related:

Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter

Typically still not worth it.
What you should really do
If metric_event is a proper partitioned table - and you have enable_partition_pruning on (as is default) - simply query the parent table with a filter matching partitioning boundaries exactly:
SELECT *
FROM   metric_event
WHERE  weeknr = EXTRACT(week FROM timestamptz '2024-04-07 00:00+2' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::int  -- cast!
LIMIT  10;

Assuming this basic table definition:
CREATE TABLE metric_event (weeknr int, data text) PARTITION BY LIST (weeknr);

CREATE TABLE metric_event_1 PARTITION OF metric_event FOR VALUES IN (1);
...
CREATE TABLE metric_event_53 PARTITION OF metric_event FOR VALUES IN (53);

Partition pruning does the job. You get a query plan like:
Limit  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36)
  ->  Seq Scan on metric_event_14 metric_event  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36)
        Filter: (weeknr = 14)

Partition bounds must be matched exactly - including the data type!
Note that date_part() returns double precision and EXTRACT returns numeric! In my example, weeknr is integer, so cast to integer! See:
fiddle
About EXTRACT / date_part()
EXTRACT and date_part() are basically equivalent. (EXTRACT in upper-case because it's really a syntax element rather than a plain function.) If in doubt, use EXTRACT. The manual:

The date_part function is modeled on the traditional Ingres
equivalent to the SQL-standard function extract:
[...]
For
historical reasons, the date_part function returns values of type
double precision. This can result in a loss of precision in certain
uses. Using extract is recommended instead.

Bold emphasis mine.

The problem is the weeknr is not present in the partitioned tables and the table is not partitioned using the partition feature of psql but using triggers. Now I need to fetch the data from the child table for last 24 hours.

@user51 Your trigger also knows why some value has to go to partition X, use that same knowledge for a partitioned table and store the week number (or date) as well. Adding more work arounds usually doesn't end well
